# Почему я не могу создать комбинацию из всех элементов из файла "1", поставив им в соответствие каждый элемент из файла "2"?

Tags: python, строки, файлы, scripts

У меня есть файл 1 
Вот пример данных:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Так же есть файл 2.
Вот пример данных:

```
10
11
12
13
14
```

Я хочу получить вот что (каждому элементу со списка 1 сопоставляю элемент со списка 2):

```
1 10
1 11
1 12
1 13
1 14
2 10
2 11
2 12
2 13
2 14
3 10
3 11
3 12
3 13
3 14
4 10
4 11
4 12
4 13
4 14
```

Делаю это так:

```
with open('long_1.txt', 'r') as long:
    with open('short_1.txt', 'r') as short:
        for i in long:
            for k in short: 
                print(i,k)
```

Получаю результат:

```
1
 10

1
 11

1
 12

1
 13

1
 14
```

Получается, что алгоритм берет только первую строчку с файла 1 и на этом останавливается. 
Почему это не работает с файлами и как исправить ошибку? 
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во вложенном цикле второй файл доходит до конца и на этом все прекращается, т.к. указатель стоит в конце файла, а чтение не начинается само по себе с начала. Нужно или открывать второй файл в теле цикла каждый раз

```
with open('long_1.txt', 'r') as long:
    for i in long:
        with open('short_1.txt', 'r') as short:
            for k in short: 
                print(i,k)
```

Или переставлять курсор в начало файла на каждой итерации внешнего цикла:

```
with open('long_1.txt', 'r') as long:
    with open('short_1.txt', 'r') as short:
        for i in long:
            short.seek(0)
            for k in short: 
                print(i,k)
```

Но лучше считать хотя бы второй файл в список и работать со списком, чтобы не читать файл каждый раз.

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать так:

```
l = open('long_1.txt', 'r')
s = open('short_1.txt', 'r')

ll = l.read().splitlines()
ss = s.read().splitlines()

for x in ll:
    for y in ss:
        print(x, y)

l.close()
s.close()
```